# JQuery Parallax not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a page with some parallex bg effect.. i have three divs with same background see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmYsC/)

when i use different bg images for all the divs then the parallex is working  but with same bg images to all the divs, its not working.

I am using this parallax jQuery plugin http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sep').parallax("50%", 0.6);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to call `parallax` on each element individually.  You can do so with `each`:

```
$('.sep').each(function(){
   $(this).parallax("50%", 0.6); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PmYsC/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique class onto each one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sep1').parallax("50%", 0.6);
  $('.sep2').parallax("50%", 0.6);
  $('.sep3').parallax("50%", 0.6);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wEpMM/

Comment: Yes. But actually the problem is i am using it in single page wordpress theme and after each section of pages this div with class sep added so then i have to dynamically add numbers to each class with php, but just wanted a workaround with js only.